# Installing computers 1 by 1

Tags: windows-10, usb, hardware, user-management, installer

I work at a company where I'm the closest thing to an IT "department"

I recieve about 10 computers monthly that I need to install from "scratch"

Windows 10 is ready on the computer but I need to set up the accounts and programs.

Basically

---

1 Admin account.
2.User account
3.All the different software.

My question is, how do I install everything(2 users,programs) in 1 go insted of manually installing the same program x10 and same user on every computer.

Is it possible to boot from USB and everything is set-up ready to go or is there some sort of software people can recommend.

First post, hope it's ok.

Comment: If your hardware is consistent, you should look at creating an image with `clonezilla` or similar and simply cloning machines as needed.

Comment: As an alternative to IvanIvan's suggestion (which is a good one, though still leaves issues with Windows 10 licensing), consider learning to use PowerShell.  Unless those programs are particularly complicated, it should be pretty easy to write a PowerShell script to handle everything after the installation of Windows 10 itself.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Thank you for the advice, I will check out both of the options.

Comment: @ivanivan Thank you, I appreciate the time you guys took to help me out!